# How to convert a pipe handle to file_descriptor(int) for Google's protobuf

Tags: c++, handle, protocol-buffers

I tried to use the handle `hPipe` as following the example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl.html):

```
  hPipe = CreateNamedPipe( 
      lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
      PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
      PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
      PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
      PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
      PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
      BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
      BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
      0,                        // client time-out 
      NULL); 

ZeroCopyOutputStream* raw_output = new FileOutputStream(hPipe);
CodedOutputStream* coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);
```

But get an error:

```
'google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream::FileOutputStream(int,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HANDLE' to 'int'
```

And here's the signature:

```
FileOutputStream(int file_descriptor, int block_size = -1);
```

So how to convert a handle to file_descriptor in c++?

**UPDATE**

I tried the recommended `_open_osfhandle` but seems not correct, reporting:

```
error C2664: '_open_osfhandle' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HANDLE' to 'intptr_t'
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is [`_open_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Which header files do I need to include besides `io.h`? Now it's reporting `_O_TEXT` in `_open_osfhandle(hPipe, _O_TEXT);` as undefined..

Comment: It sounds like you also need `#include <fcntl.h>`.

Comment: Seems `_open_osfhandle` is not the right one, now it's reporting `error C2664: _open_osfhandle : cannot convert parameter 1 from HANDLE to intptr_t`

Comment: Yes, you do have to use a cast -- in this case, it's normal and harmless (and, though not what I'd call a particularly wonderful design for the function).

Comment: I'm interested how to cast it?

Comment: @wamp: Something like: `_open_osfhandle((intptr_t)handle, _O_WHATEVER);`

Comment: Is there any library that I should link to? I'm met with this error now: `unresolved external symbol CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google`